# Minimizing size of ExtJS

Tags: grails, extjs

I'm combining Grails and ExtJS for the first time and additionally it's my first time with ExtJS. I downloaded ext-4.0.7-gpl.zip, unpacked it, and it turned out it weights 157MB. I thought I don't have to copy everything to my WEB-INF so I copied only ext-debug.js and resources dir as it seems to be only used in the [Getting started](http://file:///home/emstol/Pobrane/ext-4.0.7-gpl/docs/index.html#!/guide/getting_started) example. But it turned out to be not enough. When I copied everything it started working. So my question is what I have to copy to run application written using ExtJS? What is obligatory, what is optional, and what is obsolete? I'm pretty sure that I don't need docs, examples nor licence.txt but what with the rest? Below I attached what I see after unpacking the above zip:

```
bootstrap.js
build [dir]
builds [dir]
docs [dir]
examples [dir]
ext-all-debug.js
ext-all-debug-w-comments.js
ext-all-dev.js
ext-all.js
ext-debug.js
ext-dev.js
ext.js
index.html
jsbuilder [dir]
license.txt
locale [dir]
pkgs [dir]
release-notes.html
resources [dir]
src [dir]
welcome [dir]
```

---

**EDIT (solution)** - it turned out that the [Getting started](http://file:///home/emstol/Pobrane/ext-4.0.7-gpl/docs/index.html#!/guide/getting_started) example wasn't clear enough. I should include ext-all-debug.js instead of ext-debug.js and the example started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to keep:

```
bootstrap.js
ext-all-debug.js
ext-all-debug-w-comments.js
ext-all-dev.js
ext-all.js
ext-debug.js
ext-dev.js
ext.js
resources
```

The resources directory is optional but if you use GridPanel and etc you would need it, the directory contains all the CSS and images files.

You can also cut all the debug and dev files if you are working in production, the ext-all.js and ext.js should be compressed.

Comment: +1 Thx. The problem was located somewhere else, but your answer undeniably answers my question :)